# bundle js not created by webpack

Tags: webpack

I am trying to build a  react project with webpack  but bundle.js is not created due to some error or issue in webpack.config.js.The app directory is as follows.
 App Directory Structure 
  =>public 
        --scripts 
               --client 
                      --client.js 
        --component 
           --App.js
     --index.html 
=>server 
     --server.js
=>webpack.config.js

Now , Here is code: 
**webpack.config.js**

```js
var webpack=require('webpack');
var pathresolver=require('path');

var BUILD_DIR=pathresolver.resolve(__dirname,'./public/scripts/client');
var APP_DIR=pathresolver.resolve(__dirname,'./public/dist');

module.exports={
    devtool:'inline-source-maps',
    entry: [
        'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
        BUILD_DIR+'/client.js'
    ],
    output:{
        path:APP_DIR,
        filename:'bundle.js',
        publicPath:'/'
    },
    plugins:[
        new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),  
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),  
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()    
    ],
    module:{
        loaders:[
            {
                test:/\.js$/,
                loader:'babel-loader',
                exclude:/node_modules/,
                query:{
                     presets:['react','es2015','react-hmre'] 
                }

            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Server.js**

```js
var express= require('express');
var path=require('path');

var app=express();


//Get webapck details
var webpackconfig=require('../webpack.config.js');
var webpack=require('webpack');
var webpackDevMiddleware=require('webpack-dev-middleware');
var webpackHotMiddleware=require('webpack-hot-middleware');


var webpackcompiler=webpack(webpackconfig);

//Use middlewares
app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(webpackcompiler,{
  noInfo:true,
  publicPath:webpackconfig.output.publicPath
}));

app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(webpackcompiler));   

app.use(express.static('../public'));



 var filename = path.resolve(__dirname,'..','public','index.html');

app.use('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(filename);
});


var port=3000;
app.listen(port,function(error){
    if(error) throw err;
    console.log("Server is running at port no "+port);
})
```

**Component/App.js**

```js
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';



class App extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>Hello My name is Jalak Vora</div>
        )    
    }
}

export default App
```

**Client.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import App from '../component/App.js';



render(<App/>,document.getElementById(
    "app")
)
```

**Index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <title>Sound Wave</title>
</head>

<body>  
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="text/babel" src="dist/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I  am naive but i  think the issue is  webpack not able to find proper directory.Let me know what can be done.

Comment: Try running the compiler with `webpack` in case you're getting errors swallowed

Comment: Running with "webpack" does not show any error. Neverthless,I found bug ,it is in directory routes in server.js. Issue has  been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to the webpack/React setup aswell. However; if you are trying to setup a react environment. I suggest following the first 10 minutes of the following video,it will help you setup your environment, but from my understanding the process does not actually create a bundle.js file and somehow it does it within webpack configuration. Good luck

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IR6smI_YJDE&index=1&list=PLbeWHDJFd79RXvAeGaDXMmxL_tkb3MvdH

Answer (score 0):

I think it is due to some missing key-value pairs in scripts object of package.json file.